# Why is a parameter empty/broken in SoapClient::__getLastRequest() when attempting to use a Soap web service?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

We are attempting to call a function OrderInteractive() defined by a wsdl at https://demo2.mvrs.com/AdrConnect/AdrConnectWebService.svc?singlewsdl. It takes two parameters, a communications block with login info, and an order block with data in it. I know the login info is correct, and we are getting a response from the service, but it gives us the default "unknown error has occurred" message. When checking the result of __getLastRequest(), we get this:

```
<ns1:OrderInteractive>
    <ns1:inCommunications>
        <Communications>
            <Host>Online</Host>
            <Account>xxxxx</Account>
            <UserID>01</UserID>
            <Password>xxxxxxxxx</Password>
            <ReportTypes>
                <Type>XML2.02</Type>
            </ReportTypes>
        </Communications>
    </ns1:inCommunications>
    <ns1:inOrder/>
</ns1:OrderInteractive>
```

If you look, the order parameter is just empty. My question is why is SOAP stripping the order block, or why is the order block empty? I also tried 2 other methods of calling the function but both result in this logged in my error log:

"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'OrderInteractive'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'InOrder' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 185."

My code is below:

```
    $commsBlock = "<Communications>
                <Host>Online</Host>
                <Account>xxxxx</Account>
                <UserID>01</UserID>
                <Password>xxxxxxxxx</Password>
                <ReportTypes>
                    <Type>XML2.02</Type>
                </ReportTypes>
            </Communications>";

    $orderBlock = "<Order>
                <Handling>OL</Handling>
                <Account>xxxxx</Account>
                <ProductID>DL</ProductID>
                <State>
                    <Abbrev>" . $order['state'] . "</Abbrev>
                    <Full></Full>
                </State>
                <Subtype>3Y</Subtype>
                <Purpose>AA</Purpose>
                <License>" . $order['dln'] . "</License>
                <FirstName>" . $order['firstname'] . "</FirstName>
                <MiddleName>" . $order['middlename'] . "</MiddleName>
                <LastName>" . $order['lastname'] . "</LastName>
                <DOB>
                    <Year>" . date('Y', $order['dob']) . "</Year>
                    <Month>" . date('m', $order['dob']) . "</Month>
                    <Day>" . date( 'd', $order['dob']) . "</Day>
                </DOB>
                <Misc>TEST ORDER INTERACTIVE</Misc>
            </Order>";

    $soap_url = 'https://demo2.mvrs.com/AdrConnect/AdrConnectWebService.svc?singlewsdl'; // test system url
    $soap_params = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'cache_wsdl' => false
    );
    $_client = new SoapClient($soap_url, $soap_params);
    $params = array("inCommunications" => $commsBlock, "inOrder" => $orderBlock);

    // TRY TO SEND
    try {
        $_client->OrderInteractive($params); // works, but sends broken order node
        //$_client->__soapCall('OrderInteractive', $params); // breaks, goes to catch
        //$_client->OrderInteractive(new SoapParam($commsBlock, 'InCommunications'), new SoapParam($orderBlock, 'InOrder')); // breaks, goes to catch
    } catch(SoapFault $e) {
        capDebug(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Error: SoapFault:\n"  . $e->getMessage(), '/tmp/SOAP_errors.log');
    }
```

Comment: The error is most likely because the elements you are passing are not in the correct namespace the WSDL defines them in. Use SoapVar and SoapParam objects to build your parameters and ensure you are referencing the correct namespace the parameters are defined in. Also, I find that using a Webservice client like Boomerang for Google Chrome ( in play store ) is a good way of debugging webservices.... Especially those pesky ones created in DotNet ;(

Comment: I will revisit using SoapParam right now, thanks for your quick response John! I have Soap UI 5.2.1 running right now and using the same wsdl and the same data, we get the correct response from the service! So it must be the way I am sending it

Comment: If the elements are stripped from the getLastRequest response then you can be sure as s*#% that the parameters are not lining up with how SOAP client sees them defined in the WSDL. More times then not if frustration takes over I usually go into non-wsdl mode and construct the envelopes myself. If that's your move I find nusoap library more friendly to use in non-WSDL mode. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class inOrder {
function inOrder($xml) {
        $this->OrderXml = $xml;
    }
}

$xml_order = '<Order>
<Handling>OL</Handling>
<ProductID>DL</ProductID>
.
.
.
<Misc>TEST ORDER INTERACTIVE</Misc></Order>';

// create our order object that is needed
$order = new inOrder($xml_order);

// create our OrderInteractive parameters
$parameters = array(
    "inCommunications" => $xml_communication,
    "inOrder"          => $order
);
try {
    $xml = $_client->OrderInteractive($parameters);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n"; exit();
}
```

The code above worked. WSDL expecting a string and an object as params. Created a class for the order and used a string for the communications block, and we are receiving data fine.